# Can I use Google Apps Script to export specific information from a recurring email via Gmail?

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, automation, gmail

I'd like a script to find emails with a specific subject line and then find information within that email and export it to a doc, spreadsheet or email it to myself as plain text.

We get orders, via email, for printed clothing.
Subject:
**Your t-shirt order**
Body:
Name to print: **James**
Name to print: **Steve**
Name to print: **Ryan**

I'd love a method to get all the names, on their own, to copy and paste them to Adobe Illustrator and set them up for print.

Answer (score 1):

To save Gmail messages to a Google Spreadsheet, you need to specify the Gmail `search query` and the `sheet ID` where the matching messages are to be exported.

Found this sample code from this [tutorial](https://ctrlq.org/code/20053-save-gmail-to-google-spreadsheet).

```
var SEARCH_QUERY = "label:inbox is:unread to:me";

// Credit: https://gist.github.com/oshliaer/70e04a67f1f5fd96a708

function getEmails_(q) {
    var emails = [];
    var threads = GmailApp.search(q);
    for (var i in threads) {
        var msgs = threads[i].getMessages();
        for (var j in msgs) {
            emails.push([msgs[j].getBody().replace(/<.*?>/g, '\n')
                .replace(/^\s*\n/gm, '').replace(/^\s*/gm, '').replace(/\s*\n/gm, '\n')
            ]);
        }
    }
    return emails;
}

function appendData_(sheet, array2d) {
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, array2d.length, array2d[0].length).setValues(array2d);
}

function saveEmails() {
    var array2d = getEmails_(SEARCH_QUERY);
    if (array2d) {
        appendData_(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(), array2d);
    }
}
```

You can also check this related [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/VZ95K8uCfOI) and [tutorial](http://www.i-programmer.info/projects/36-web/5381-gmail-spreadsheets-and-google-app-script.html).